# Should I use "with" or "on" in the following case?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

> A thesis **with** flies kept him awake the whole week
>
> A thesis **on** flies kept him awake the whole week

What's the correct option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do 'thesis **on**' something.

> [thesis *(on something)*](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/thesis?q=thesis) - *Students must submit a **thesis on** an agreed subject within four years.*

However, 'thesis **with**' is also possible but then, it'll be like..

> A **thesis with** sprawling ideas about using wearable technologies